# Objective-C RabbitMQ client not receiving messages

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, rabbitmq

I am developing an iOS application and using profmaad's objective-c client for RabbitMQ
https://github.com/profmaad/librabbitmq-objc

this is the code I am using to establish a connection and start listening to events:

```
-(void)establish{

   AMQPConnection *connection = [[AMQPConnection alloc] init];
   [connection connectToHost:<host> onPort:<port number>];
   [connection loginAsUser:<username> withPasswort:<password> onVHost:<vHost>];

   AMQPChannel *channel = [connection openChannel];
   AMQPQueue *queue = [[AMQPQueue alloc] initWithName:<queue name> onChannel:channel isPassive:NO isExclusive:NO isDurable:NO getsAutoDeleted:NO];

   AMQPConsumer *consumer = [[AMQPConsumer alloc] initForQueue:queue onChannel:channel useAcknowledgements:YES isExclusive:NO receiveLocalMessages:NO];
   AMQPConsumerThread *consumerThread = [[AMQPConsumerThread alloc] initWithConsumer:consumer];
   consumerThread.delegate = self;
}
-(void)amqpConsumerThreadReceivedNewMessage:(AMQPMessage *)theMessage
{
   NSLog(@"message = %@", theMessage);
   NSLog(@"message.body = %@", theMessage.body);
}
```

the problem is, the amqpConsumerThreadReceivedNewMessage is never called!

Answer (score 3):

You need to start the consumer thread first.

```
[consumerThread start];
```